# How to disable browser default keybindings with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am building an editor with custom keybindings to control its behaviors.  It worked well, but if I set a keybinding pattern that is already used by browser, my defined keybindings are ignored by the browser.

A list of browser keybindings: https://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers/

My question is, how can I override these keybindings?  Is it possible to do so with Javascript?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can achieve it using keydown, keypress, etc key events. but its sequence depends on browsers. So you have to check the first event on your browser, prevent it and execute what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either through an event listener or an "onkeydown" attribute, you can conditionally target combinations of key/keyCode, metaKey(command/windows), shiftKey, altKey, and ctrlKey:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
  const {key, keyCode, metaKey, shiftKey, altKey, ctrlKey} = e; 
  if(key === "c" && (ctrlKey || metaKey)){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("copy prevented");
  }
});
```

```html
HIGHLIGHT AND TRY TO COPY THIS TEXT WITH CTRL + C or COMMAND + C
```

Comment: The preventDefault in your example didn't work for me (the copy worked for me). Setup: Mac 13.4.1, Chrome 115.0.5790.170